# Best way to binding context of a itemselect in collectionview to new page all in MVVM

Tags: maui

I have a content page binding to `ViewModel` example ListPage binding `ListPageViewModel`, this ListPage have a `CollectionView` when the user SELECT ITEM is TAP  excute the funtion `OnItemSelected` the "item" has a data model "ClientesCrm", all the code works with the MVVM, I try to find the best way to binding "item" context to a new page example `DetailPage` binding `DetailPageViewModel`, I don't want to make a new request to the "database" / "api" if alredy I have all the info in the item like.. `item.firtsname` `item.lastname`, etc

`ListPage.xaml` part of code;

```xml
<CollectionView 
    x:Name="Especialidadrec"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSubasta}"
    SelectionMode="Single">
```

`ListPageViewModel` part of code:

```cs
private ClientesCrm _selectedItem;

public ClientesCrm SelectedItem
{
    get => _selectedItem;
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _selectedItem, value);
        OnItemSelected(value);
    }
}
async void OnItemSelected(ClientesCrm item)
{
    if (item == null)
        return;
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("clientesdetalles");
    // ----> Register in AppShell.cs 
    //Routing.RegisterRoute("clientesdetalles",typeof(DetailPage));
}
```

When the `CollectionView` load the info  I have all the data I need. What is the best way to pass these "item" `item.name`, `item.lastname`, `item.age` to the new page all in MVVM? If I don't use the `ViewModel` there no doubts, but I need it to work all my app in the MVVM

Comment: Please format your code. It's currently unreadable.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation#pass-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what is the best way to pass this "item" item.name item.lastname
> item.age to the new page all in mvvm

Primitive data can be passed as string-based query parameters when performing URI-based programmatic navigation. This is achieved by appending `?` after a route, followed by a query parameter id, `=`, and a value.

For example:

```
async void OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string elephantName = (e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as Animal).Name;
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"elephantdetails?name={elephantName}");
}
```

And for your requirement, you can pass the `Item` as a whole.

Object-based navigation data can be passed with a `GoToAsync` overload that specifies an `IDictionary<string, object>` argument:

For example:

```
async void OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Animal animal = e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as Animal;
    var navigationParameter = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "Bear", animal }
    };
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"beardetails", navigationParameter);
}
```

For more information, you can refer to the official document [Pass data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation#pass-data).

And you can also check the sample here:[.NET MAUI - Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/dotnet/maui-samples/fundamentals-shell/).

Comment: the problem was resolve, using the NET MAUI documentation